# cancel knockout ratelimit extender if user press Enter on an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I send an AJAX request to server which include page number that I want from the server.

I get this page number from user using an input box.

I use this code:

```js
   (function($) {
     $(function() {
         // Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
         function CartableViewModel(totalItems) {
           var self = this;
           // Editable data
           self.data = ko.observable();
           self.pageIndex = ko.observable(1).extend({
             rateLimit: {
               method: "notifyWhenChangesStop",
               timeout: 1500
             }
           });


           ko.computed(function() {
             Mostafa.myApp.Order.Cartable("CreatorID=23 & (CreatorID=23|CreatorID>23)", self.pageSize(), function(data) {
               self.data(data);
             });
           });
         });
     }
     Mostafa.myApp.Order.CartableViewModel = new CartableViewModel();
     ko.applyBindings(Mostafa.myApp.Order.CartableViewModel);
   });
   $("#form_page_select").on("submit", function() {
   return false;
   });
   })(jQuery);
```

my HTML is:

```html
<form id="form_page_select">
  <input type="number" id="input_page_select" min="1" data-bind='value: pageIndex, valueUpdate: ["input", "keypress"]' />
</form>
```

actually I send this AJAX request with another java script method which it's name is "Mostafa.myApp.Order.Cartable()" and it works fine.

my Question is: How can I send this Ajax call not only after timeout, but if the user press enter on this input field.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: if you want to send ajax on enter button too, then removing submit listener of jquery and use submit knockout binding. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use subscribe from knockoutjs for the functionlaity you are looking for.

Small demo of same

```js
function model(){
    var self = this;
    self.pageIndex = ko.observable(5).extend({ rateLimit: 1500 });
    self.pageIndex.subscribe(function(newValue) {
      alert(newValue);
      //Call here your ajax call
      //Subscribe will be called on every change of your PageIndex
    });
};
var mod = new model();
ko.applyBindings(mod);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="input_page_select" min="1" data-bind='value: pageIndex, valueUpdate: ["input", "keypress"]' />
```

Comment: Thannks for your answer, But I want to keep my raetlimit extender, it means if user doesn't press Enter this property change in 1500 ms.

Comment: Updated answer with rateLimit. .extend({ rateLimit: 1500 });